# Opengl Camera and multiplying matrixes

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, camera

I Am currently having alot of problems with the camera I am making. The problem occurs with my matrix rotation I am doing as this website says to avoid gimble lock..

> One of the first problems you will note is that the order you apply
>   these rotations matter. As previously stated, a rotation matrix is an
>   orientation transform. Each transform defines a new coordinate system,
>   and the next transform is based on an object in the new space. For
>   example, if we apply the roll first, we have now changed what the axis
>   for the subsequent yaw is.

And when i perform this for example if I am wanted to pitch around the current x axis the x axis also changes in my axis to rotation method which is obviously wrong. Ive look around alot and cant find any solution. I have tried alot of differenet version of the axis angle rotation matrix..

```
void FrustumCamera::xAxisRotation(float angle)
{
    Vector3<float> x = m_orientation.getXAxis();
    Matrix4<float> matrix = m_orientation.axisAngleRotation(x,angle);
    m_orientation = matrix*m_orientation;
    normalise(m_orientation.getXAxis());
    normalise(m_orientation.getYAxis());
    normalise(m_orientation.getZAxis());
}
void FrustumCamera::yAxisRotation(float angle)
{
    Vector3<float> y = m_orientation.getYAxis();

    Matrix4<float> matrix = m_orientation.axisAngleRotation(y,angle);
    m_orientation = matrix*m_orientation;

    normalise(m_orientation.getXAxis());
    normalise(m_orientation.getYAxis());
    normalise(m_orientation.getZAxis());
}

Matrix4<Type> Matrix4<Type>::operator*(Matrix4& matrix)
{
    Matrix4<Type> temp(m_matrix);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            Type total = 0;
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
            {

                total += m_matrix[i][k]*matrix.getAt(k,j);;

            }
            temp.setAt(i,j,total);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
template <class Type>
Matrix4<Type> Matrix4<Type>::axisAngleRotation(Vector3<Type> axis, const Type angle)
{
    Type radians = angle * (double)degToRad;
    Matrix4<Type> temp;
    float c = cosf(radians);
    float s = sinf(radians);
    float t = 1.0f - c;

    float x = axis.x;
    float y = axis.y;
    float z = axis.z;

    temp.setAt(0,0, c+x*x*(t));
    temp.setAt(0,1, x*y*(t)-z*s);
    temp.setAt(0,2, x*z*(t)+y*s);
    temp.setAt(0,3, 0.0f);

    temp.setAt(1,0, y*x*(t)+z*s);
    temp.setAt(1,1, c+y*y*(t));
    temp.setAt(1,2, y*z*(t)-x*s);
    temp.setAt(1,3, 0.0f);

    temp.setAt(2,0, z*x*(t)-y*s);
    temp.setAt(2,1, z*y*(1-c)+x*s);
    temp.setAt(2,2, c+z*z*(t));
    temp.setAt(2,3, 0.0f);

    temp.setAt(3,0, 0.0f);
    temp.setAt(3,1, 0.0f);
    temp.setAt(3,2, 0.0f);
    temp.setAt(3,3, 1.0f);

    return temp;
}
void OpenGLRenderer::startDraw(unsigned long mask)
{
    //sortBuffer();                                     // sort draw queue
    clearBuffers(mask);                                 // clear buffers
    loadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1*m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().x,-1*m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().y,-1*m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().z);// load identity
    glMultMatrixf(m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getMatrix());
    glTranslatef(m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().x,m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().y,m_frustumCamera->getViewMatrix().getTranslationAxis().z);

    matrixStackPush();                                          
}
```

Comment: What kind of camera are you trying to make? FPS style camera, or 6DOF (spaceship)?

Comment: 6DOF(spaceship) without the z axis rotation (roll)

Answer (score 2):

I think order of multiplication can cause the problem, instead of

```
m_orientation = matrix*m_orientation;
```

try

```
m_orientation = m_orientation * matrix;
```

Comment: Ive just tried this, it did help a little bit. The camera still rotates strangely I fear my translations of the camera are wrong. But I have tried every possible way of placing the translations still no luck!